# My python code keeps returning it's results in UTC time

Tags: python, api, time

I have this code:

```
def get_events(day, service):
    # Call the Calendar API
    date = datetime.datetime.combine(day, datetime.datetime.min.time())
    end = datetime.datetime.combine(day, datetime.datetime.max.time())
    gmt = timezone('Europe/London')
    date = date.astimezone(gmt)
    end = end.astimezone(gmt)
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=date.isoformat(), timeMax=end.isoformat(),
                                        singleEvents=True,
                                        orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])
```

Using the Google Calendar API
Yet I still seem to always get my replies in UTC time, 5 hours behind my time. Any help appreciated

Comment: Which problem are you facing?

Comment: It gives me the UTC time for my events

Answer (score 0):

```
gmt = timezone('Europe/London')
date = date.astimezone(gmt)
end = end.astimezone(gmt)
```

You get what you asked for.

**Update**: If the datetime object is from a different timezone, but does not contain timezone info ("naive datetime") first add that info:

```
gmt = timezone('Europe/London')
googletz = timezone("EST") # not sure if this one or some other
date = date.replace(tzinfo=googletz).astimezone(gmt)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this? I asked for gmt and got UTC?

Comment: UTC **is** GMT (with some subtle differences, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time - but for practical use these are synonyms).

Comment: Oh right, apologies, my point was that I was expecting the Europe/London timezone but didn't seem to get that

Comment: I would guess the times returned by Google are not in UTC, but rather in some US timezone (EST?) - so you need to tell `datetime` that before converting to UTC. See update to my answer.